# Wordpress Excerpt Formatting

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm having issues with the excerpt showing multiple paragraphs as a single on my wordpress install.

Basically for example, if I were to go into an article such as this: http://www.grapplearts.com/2015/08/the-2-easiest-takedowns-for-no-gi-submission-grappling-and-mma/

The paragraphs are broken up appropriately with `<p>` tags.  But on my articles page http://www.grapplearts.com/articles/ those multiple lines of text are all crammed into one `<p>`. Inspecting the paragraph shows that each line is stripped of the tag except for the first and last, but the actual return spacing is still there.

How would I make it so the excerpt shows the paragraphs as separate?

Comment: You haven't shared any code...but it's possible `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` is being wrapped in `<p>` tags (which is resulting in invalid HTML, and is throwing things off). Again, impossible to know without seeing the template code for that location.

Comment: Yeah, without seeing code it's hard to say, but `the_excerpt()` is ran through `wpautop()` which will turn any double line breaks into `<p>` tags. I'd hazard a guess that the template is using `get_the_excerpt()` which doesn't get `<p>`'s added.